# Mapserver Layer Connection 2 database

Tags: mapserver

i use mapinfo .tab for show the map, and i want to use SQl Server To select the other data, can mapserver have 2 connection in layer? or there are other ways this my .MAP layer configuration.

```
LAYER
    NAME layer_name
    TYPE POLYGON
    STATUS ON
    CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
    CONNECTION "./map/1172.TAB"
 >>>CONNECTION "connection sql"<<<
    DATA "select from mapinfo join to sqlserver"
    METADATA
      "wms_title" "Sabang"
    END

    PROJECTION
      "init=epsg:32646"
    END

    CLASS
        NAME "Elevation Poly 5"
        STYLE
            COLOR        232 232 232
            OUTLINECOLOR 32 32 32
          END
    END
END # Layer
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't merge the two layers directly in the mapfile. Instead you can use the [OGR Virtual Format](http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html) to join the Mapinfo-File and the data from the SQL Server. In the Mapfile you have to use the `CONNECTIONTYPE OGR` and to set the `CONNECTION` to the file with the virtual format definition. You can find more innformation in the [Mapserver documentation](http://www.mapserver.org/input/vector/VirtualSpatialData.html).